# How does SquishIt deal with global variables and functions

Tags: javascript, squishit

I'm not sure if I will use squishIt page by page or use one combined file with all JS in the project.
I'm a bit worried that some global variables in my js files will crash into each other.
Does squishIt deal with this?

I know that there shouldn't be any global variables. But isn't me that build the project so here I am with alot of JS and with global variables.

Quite same question about functions. What happens if I have the same name of some functions in different JS files and the combined them into one?

Is .ForeRelease() purpose to make it work without changeing debug into false in web.config?

Comment: Are you saying that you have the same global var declared in multiple files? If so, how does the app work when they are used together in a non-compressed fashion? Typically these tools will concatenate all the JS together before trying to do any compression.

Comment: Yes if I have global variabels declared in multiple files with the same name of the variabels. Dont know if so is the case, but will it still work when I combined all my JS into one file. Or will it fail on some way?

Comment: I can't say definitively whether or not it will fail, but it's certainly possible that the global variables will overwrite each other at inappropriate moments.